# Getting Error thrown when TCP connect lost

Tags: c#

I have a block of code that "listens" on a TCP port and just sends an string back no matter what is sent.  The issue is the client side is just testing to see if the port is active then disconnecting.  At which point I get an error thrown. 
Cannot access a disposed object
Object name: 'System.Net.Socket.NetworkSystem'

I think the issue is that this code is on a thread and when the connection closes the while loop references a disposed object... how should I prevent the error from firing when the client closes the connection?

```
  //Cretae listener to accept client connections
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // Receive buffer
        int bytesRcvd; // Received byte count
        while (ServiceRunning)  // Run forever, accepting and servicing connections
        {
            try
            {
                // Receive until client closes connection, indicated by 0 return value
                int totalBytesEchoed = 0;

//I THINK THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS .. THE CLIENTSTREAM.READ???

                while (((bytesRcvd = clientStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0) && (ServiceRunning))
                {
                    clientStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                    WriteEventToWindowsLog("GSSResponderService", "Received "+System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rcvBuffer), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                }

                WriteEventToWindowsLog("GSSResponderService", "Responded to " + totalBytesEchoed.ToString() + " bytes.", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);


                // Close the stream and socket. We are done with this client!
                clientStream.Close();
                tcpClient.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
//THIS IS GETTING TRIGGERED WHEN A CONNECTION IS LOST
                WriteEventToWindowsLog("GSSResponderService", "Error:" + e.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
                clientStream.Close();
                tcpClient.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN, [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) method of [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) class throws *IOException* when the underlying Socket is closed and *ObjectDisposedException* when the NetworkStream is closed or there is a failure reading from the network. The same exceptions are thrown by *Write* method.

Therefore it shoud be enough to catch these 2 exception types and take appropriate action in exception handlers.

```
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // Receive buffer
    int bytesRcvd; // Received byte count
    while (ServiceRunning)  // Run forever, accepting and servicing connections
    {
        try
        {
            // Receive until client closes connection, indicated by 0 return value
            int totalBytesEchoed = 0;

            try
            {
                while (((bytesRcvd = clientStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0) && (ServiceRunning))
                {
                    clientStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                    WriteEventToWindowsLog("GSSResponderService", "Received "+System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rcvBuffer), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                }
            }
            catch(IOException)
            {
                //HERE GOES CODE TO HANDLE CLIENT DISCONNECTION
            }
            catch(ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //HERE GOES CODE TO HANDLE CLIENT DISCONNECTION
            }

            WriteEventToWindowsLog("GSSResponderService", "Responded to " + totalBytesEchoed.ToString() + " bytes.", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);


            // Close the stream and socket. We are done with this client!
            clientStream.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteEventToWindowsLog("GSSResponderService", "Error:" + e.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            clientStream.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```